# How can I optimize my javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys
How can I better optimize my js object.. As you can see there is a lot of repeating and I want to find better way to write this object. I'm new to JS thats why so fool question.
Thanks in advance.

```
//field odject
var $field = $("#field");
var field = {
    width: $field.width(),
    offsetTop: $field.offset().top,
    offsetLeft: $field.offset().left,
    offsetRight: $field.offset().left + $field.width(),
    offsetBottom: $field.offset().top + $field.height()
};
```

Comment: You could store `$field.offset()` in another variable. Other than that it looks fine

Comment: Maybe try asking here: http://hashcode.ru/

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could take a look at the second part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17550761/592253

Comment: You should make your question a bit clearer, then ask it on [CodeReview.SE] if there’s nothing specific that’s wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function field($sel){

     //field odject
     var $field = $($sel);
     var offset = $field.offset();
     var field = {
         width: $field.width(),
         offsetTop:offset.top,
         offsetLeft: offset.left,
         offsetRight: offset.left + $field.width(),
         offsetBottom: offset.top + $field.height()
     };

     return field;

}
```

You extend your functionality by creating a constructor and return the object from your function.

Comment: thanks for answer. Looks better, but how I can receive properties from field object. Example: console.log(field.offsetBottom);

Comment: That should work... http://jsfiddle.net/JZAxp/1/

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing your asking how to not make so many method calls when constructing this object?

You could just use some variables to cache the values you use multiple times:

```
var $field = $("#field");
var width = $field.width();
var offset = $field.offset();
var top = offset.top;
var left = offset.left;

var field = {
    width: width,
    offsetTop: top,
    offsetLeft: left,
    offsetRight: left + width,
    offsetBottom: top + $field.height()
};
```